# 2x SSD like one drive 12.10

Tags: 12.10, raid, ssd, lvm

I want to do a clean install of ubuntu 12.10. I got 2x 40GB SSD's. I want to have them like one drive. (like RAID0), is there a way to do this with LVM, in the graphical Ubuntu 12.10 installation?

I know I can do this with Ubuntu server, RAID0 and then installing the ubuntu-dekstop package.

Comment: Are you certain that you know what you are doing? A RAID0 with SSDs seems strange to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sitting on RAID0 with Ubuntu 12.10 now. But I installed some dodgy ppa's and have to do a clean install. Now I want to try  with LVM.

Comment: Why bother with RAID0 when Linux uses a directory structure (mount point) to add the 2nd disc to root?

Comment: Do you meen like mounting one disc as / and one like /home? If I do that, I'm restricted to use 40 GB on root and 40 at home. (I got 40GB SSD's not 80 btw. I wrote wrong at the question).

Ps. sorry for my English. 2nd language.

Comment: @fyksen OK I understood that :) But... you can put /etc on the 2nd disc. Or /usr. Just create more partitions on the 2nd disc. Then again I see nothing wrong with a 40 Gb home disc to store documents ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it that way. But would be much better for me to mount everything on "/".

Is it possible to do this with LVM?